# Moving a Pacman

Tags: java, swing, animation, pacman

This is a program I wrote for creating a pacman. I now want the Pacman to move in a straight line from a random start point to a random goal point.
Could you please suggest how to do it.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 * Main class for pacman example. All it does is create a frame and put
 * the pacman panel in it. 
 */


    public class PacmanGUI extends JFrame{
    private Pacman pc;
        public PacmanGUI(){
        super("Pacman");
        pc = new Pacman();
        this.getContentPane().add(pc);  
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PacmanGUI();
    }

}
```

---

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

/**
 * Pacman class that extends JPanel and paints a pacman animation.
 * It uses Timers and Actionlistener to do the Animation.
 *
 */

    public class Pacman extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
        private int figureSize = 50;
        private static final int DELAY = 200;
        private double mouthOpenPercentages[] = {.1,.5};
        private Timer animationTimer;
        private int mouthState = 0;
        private Point pacManPosition;

    /**
     * No args constructor that starts the animation.
     */
        public Pacman(){
        startAnimation();
        }

    /**
     * Overriden paintComponent method that paints pacman.
     */
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
        pacManPosition = new Point(this.getWidth()/2 - figureSize/2,
                                    this.getHeight()/2 - figureSize/2);
        g.fillRect(0,0,this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

    drawPacMan(g);
        mouthState = (++mouthState) % mouthOpenPercentages.length;
    }
    /**
     * Stops the animation by stopping the animation timer.     
     */
    public void stopAnimation(){ animationTimer.stop(); }

    /**
     * Method do deal with actionevents that are triggered. In this
     * case we only have actionevents being triggered from our timer 
     * and by the more usual case of a button click.
     */
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ repaint(); }

    /**
     * Gets the size that this component would like to be.
     */
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){ return new Dimension(400,400); }

    /**
     * Gets the minimum size for this component. 
     */
    public Dimension getMinimumSize(){ return new Dimension(200,200); }

    /**
     * Starts the animation by setting a timer. When this timer goes 
     * off the actionPerformed method will be triggered, which in 
     * turn triggers the painting.
     */
    private void startAnimation(){
        if (animationTimer == null){
            mouthState = 0;
            animationTimer = new Timer(DELAY, this);
            animationTimer.start();
        } else {  //continue animating..
            if (!animationTimer.isRunning())
            animationTimer.restart();
        }
    }
    /**
     * Draws our little pacman on the given graphics canvas.
     * @param g
     */
    private void drawPacMan(Graphics g){
        Color c = g.getColor();
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.fillOval(pacManPosition.x, pacManPosition.y, figureSize, figureSize);
        //Change color back to original and draw pacman's mouth
        g.setColor(c);
        //calculate mouth offsets
        int yOffset = (int)((figureSize/2)*mouthOpenPercentages[mouthState]);
        //draw the mouth cutout.
        int x[] = {pacManPosition.x + figureSize/2, pacManPosition.x + figureSize, pacManPosition.x + figureSize};
        int y[] = {pacManPosition.y + figureSize/2, 
                   pacManPosition.y + figureSize/2 + yOffset,
                   pacManPosition.y + figureSize/2 - yOffset};
        g.fillPolygon(x, y, x.length);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

You have to manage two animations at the same time.

The first, which you've already coded, opens and closes the Pacman's mouth.

The second animation is responsible for moving the Pacman from one location to another.

### Solution - Sprite class

I suggest you create a Sprite class.  The Sprite class would be responsible for holding the current position of the sprite, the next position of the sprite, and the speed at which the sprite moves.

You would extend Sprite to get one Pacman class, and a Chaser class with 4 instances.

### Pacman class

The Pacman class would be responsible for the mouth animation.

### Chaser class

The Chaser class would be responsible for determining whether to chase the Pacman, or run away from the Pacman.

### Swing Tips

You should not extend Java Swing components, unless you are overriding one or more of the component classes.  You should use Swing components.

You should always start your Swing GUI on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).  You do this by executing the invokeLater method of SwingUtilities.

You should have a GUI model, separate from your GUI components.  The three classes I defined would be part of your GUI model.  You also need to lay out a maze.

Comment: Swing GUI on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) is something that Java will put in for you if you use the GUI builder. The class will run fine without it. Can you explain how this will make the class safe or is it necessary to put all of your code in the EDT.

Comment: @user3376708: Sun (now Oracle) says to put your Swing components on the [Event Dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) (EDT).  All of your Swing components should be created and updated on the EDT.  Otherwise, you could encounter some hard to debug race conditions.  I have enough trouble getting my own code to work properly without trying to create other problems by ignoring the advice of Oracle experts.

Comment: So every time that you create a swing component do you have to create a Runnable() thread or just the one many thread in the main method. Actually if you could put up a couple of code examples would help. Link them in through a fiddle site if you can.

Comment: @user3376708: Choose any of the Java Swing articles in [Java Articles](http://java-articles.info/articles/).

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `Pacman` class you would need to create 2 more values to store the start and end points.  You already have `private Point pacManPosition;` declared so I would also declare these as `Point`s.  You'll want to set `pacManPosition` initially to the start point.

```
Point start = // random start point
Point end = // random end point
Point pacManPoint = new Point(start);
```

Now you'll want to determine the speed you want your Pacman to move at, let's say 2 pixels per frame.

```
int speed = 2;
```

To determine how much to move the Pacman each frame, we'll need to do some calculations. First, get the distance of the line -

```
double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(end.x - start.x, 2) + 
                            Math.pow(end.y - start.y, 2));
```

Then we calculate how many frames it will take to go that distance at the speed we want.

```
int totalFrames= (int)Math.round(distance / speed);
```

And add a frame counter -

```
int frame = 0;
```

Now, look inside your `paintComponent` method. Right now you're setting `pacManPosition` to the same point (the center of the panel) each time it paints. What you want to do here instead is to update `pacManPosition` each frame until it gets to the end position.  You're doing something similar lower in `paintComponent` where you're updating `mouthState` each time to get the mouth to animate. For animating position it will look like -

```
if (frame < totalFrames) {
    pacManPosition.x = start.x + frame * (end.x - start.x) / totalFrames;
    pacManPosition.y = start.y + frame * (end.y - start.y) / totalFrames;
    frame++;
}
```

This is only one way to do movement animation, and it assumes several things - constant speed, no need to avoid obstacles, no player control. The calculation in totalFrames isn't exact - it moves pacMan close to the end point, but there's no guarantee it will end exactly there. It is also tied to the frame rate, which has drawbacks.  There are many, many other ways to do this depending on the situation.